# Loop through xml resetting var on each loop

Tags: c#, xml, xpath

I am sure this is relatively simple. I want to loop through the below xml, each time I hit a new namespace, reset var.

```
    XmlNodeList nodes = reports.SelectNodes("Reports/namespace");
        foreach (XmlNode NSpace in nodes)
        {
            List<string> newlist = new List<string>();

            //loop through checks one by one.
            foreach (XmlElement element in reports.GetElementsByTagName("report"))
            {
                doStuff
            }
         }
```

I know this is wrong as it is simply looping through the entire xml block 4 times (for each namespace) due to the below.

```
foreach (XmlElement element in reports.GetElementsByTagName("report"))
```

Can someone advise the xpath or correct loop I need?

XML

```
    <Reports>
    <namespace Type="first">
    <report>
    <name>first_1</name>
    </report>
    <report>
    <name>first_2</name>
    </report>
    <report>
    <name>first_3</name>
    </report>
    </namespace>
    <namespace Type="Second">
    <report>
    <name>Second_1</name>
    </report>
    </namespace>
    <namespace Type="Third">
    <report>
    <name>Third_1</name>
    </report>
    </namespace>
    <namespace Type="Fourth">
    <report>
    <name>Fourth_1</name>
    </report>
    </namespace>
    </Reports>
```

Answer (score 1):

Well you're ignoring your outer iteration variable. I suspect you just want to change your inner loop to:

```
XmlElement namespaceElement = (XmlElement) NSpace;
foreach (XmlElement element in namespaceElement.GetElementsByTagName("report"))
{
    // doStuff
}
```

Alternatively, change the type of your iteration variable too:

```
foreach (XmlElement NSpace in nodes)
{
    List<string> newlist = new List<string>();

    foreach (XmlElement element in NSpace.GetElementsByTagName("report"))
    {
        // ...
    }
}
```

(I would also change the name of the iteration variable, but that's another matter.)

If you're using .NET 3.5 or higher, you might also want to consider using LINQ to XML, which I certainly find simpler for this sort of thing.

Comment: Error 36 'System.Xml.XmlNode' does not contain a definition for 'GetElementsByTagName' and no extension method 'GetElementsByTagName' accepting a first argument of type 'System.Xml.XmlNode' could be found (are you missing a using directive or an assembly reference?)

Comment: @user1156000: Edited... (this is one reason I prefer LINQ to XML)